# Stack multiple arrays in with different length (numbers of rows)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have 5 columns in a sheet but they all have a specific number of rows. How can I get a single column with all of the values stacked?

I'm new to Excel and I can't find an easy way to do it

Comment: `TOCOL()` surely !

Comment: I don't know why but this function is not in my excel

Comment: It is only available in Office 365 with subscription.

Comment: `Power Query` is one of the better option to unpivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solutions are for noobs. Take a look at this absurdly complicated formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$5,IF(MOD(AGGREGATE(15,6,(((ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($A$1:$E$5))))^1)+(COLUMN(INDIRECT("C1:C"&COLUMNS($A$1:$E$5),FALSE))^1-1)*(ROWS(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($A$1:$E$5))))^1)/(NOT(ISBLANK($A$1:$E$5))),ROW(1:1)-ROW($1:$1)+1),ROWS($A$1:$E$5))=0,ROWS($A$1:$E$5),MOD(AGGREGATE(15,6,(((ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($A$1:$E$5))))^1)+(COLUMN(INDIRECT("C1:C"&COLUMNS($A$1:$E$5),FALSE))^1-1)*(ROWS(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($A$1:$E$5))))^1)/(NOT(ISBLANK($A$1:$E$5))),ROW(1:1)-ROW($1:$1)+1),ROWS($A$1:$E$5))),(QUOTIENT(AGGREGATE(15,6,(((ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($A$1:$E$5))))^1)+(COLUMN(INDIRECT("C1:C"&COLUMNS($A$1:$E$5),FALSE))^1-1)*(ROWS(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($A$1:$E$5))))^1)/(NOT(ISBLANK($A$1:$E$5))),ROW(1:1)-ROW($1:$1)+1),ROWS($A$1:$E$5))+IF(MOD(AGGREGATE(15,6,(((ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($A$1:$E$5))))^1)+(COLUMN(INDIRECT("C1:C"&COLUMNS($A$1:$E$5),FALSE))^1-1)*(ROWS(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($A$1:$E$5))))^1)/(NOT(ISBLANK($A$1:$E$5))),ROW(1:1)-ROW($1:$1)+1),ROWS($A$1:$E$5))=0,0,1)))
```

It assumes that your data are stored in range A1:E5. Just change the reference `$A$1:$E$5` to whatever you need and then drag down the formula accordingly to your need.